# Radio button not getting clicked in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, infragistics

I am migrating my project from .NET framework 3.5 to 4.5.2 and Infragistics control used in UI from 8.2 to 16.2 version. After migration i am not able to click on a radio button placed inside a grid within igRibon window of Infragistics. Radio button has just a checked property Binded. 
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4WTk.png)

Comment: Can you please add your code to your question? If you have any questions, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you try Like    <input name="rtButton" type="radio" 
                    value='<%# Eval("D") %>' />

Comment: @SinghKailash It's a WPF question.

Comment: @ArApurva Please paste the code into your question as text. Screenshots of code are very unpopular here. You are much more likely to get useful responses when the code is pasted into your question as text.